# Write an Arbitrary Value Not Found in a Case Class Using Play's (2.2) Scala JSON Combinators

Tags: json, scala, playframework, functional-programming, combinators

I'd like to implement a `Writes` that emits a JSON object that's not found in the class being serialized.

For case class:

```
case class Foo(i:Int, s:String)
```

I'm looking to produce:

```
{
  "i": <int>,
  "s": "<string>",
  "other": "Some value."
}
```

The naïve first attempt was:

```
val writes: Writes[Foo] = ((
  (__ \ "i").write[Int] and
    (__ \ "s").write[String] and
    (__ \ "other").write("Some value.")
  )(unlift(Foo.unapply))
```

Naturally, that won't compile as the subsequent `and` calls produce a `CanBuild3` and `Foo`'s `unapply` produces a `Tuple2`. I'd looked into appending a value to the result, producing a `Tuple3`, but what I've found [looks pretty bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349439/how-to-append-or-prepend-an-element-to-a-tuple-in-scala) and the [language maintainers will not implement it](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7305).

There are ways to work-around this, but I'd rather not pollute my model classes with these decorator values I'd like added to the resulting JSON.

Any suggestions?

It's worth noting you *can* go the other direction, providing values with `Reads.pure` for cases where a value does not exist in JSON but is specified by the resulting object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this pretty straightforwardly by desugaring a bit:

```
val writes: Writes[Foo] = (
  (__ \ "i").write[Int] and
  (__ \ "s").write[String] and
  (__ \ "other").write[String]
)(foo => (foo.i, foo.s, "Some value."))
```

The `unlift(Foo.unapply)` is just a fancy way to get a function from a `Foo` to a tuple of the kind required by the preceding applicative builder expression, and you can replace it with your own function that can add whatever you want.

If you *really* wanted even cleaner syntax, you could use [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless):

```
import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._

val writes: Writes[Foo] = (
  (__ \ "i").write[Int] and
  (__ \ "s").write[String] and
  (__ \ "other").write[String]
)(_ :+ "Some value.")
```

It's beautiful, but may be overkill.

Comment: Good suggestions! The first was a thought, but it becomes more difficult to use with higher arity products. Oh well. If the Shapeless syntax is that easy—and the library's good for production—then I'm going to try messing around with it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use an object builder that implements an `unapply` that returns the extra values. This makes the Writes cleaner, but adds a new object. I have found this useful though as both the apply and unapply method can be used for extra massaging of data into the final object (eg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22504468/1085606)

Example:

```
case class Foo(i: Int, s: String)

object FooBuilder {
  def unapply(foo: Foo): Option[(Int, String, String)] = {
    Some((foo.i, foo.s, "Some extra value"))
  }
}

val writes: Writes[Foo] = ((
  (__ \ "i").write[Int] and
    (__ \ "s").write[String] and
    (__ \ "other").write[String]
  )(unlift(FooBuilder.unapply))
```