# How to transform Array(e1, e2) into (e1, e2) using Scala 2.11.6 API only?

Tags: scala

Given:

```
scala> val ss = "hello_world".split("_")
ss: Array[String] = Array(hello, world)
```

How to turn `ss` into a tuple `(hello, world)` with a function of `Array` (on `ss`)? I'm thinking about a function so the above snippet would end up as `"hello_world".split("_").to[Tuple2]` or alike.

Is it possible using Scala 2.11.6 API only?

Comment: Not really a dup I think

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you don't know how many elements will result from the split, you can't say anything about the type of the resulting tuple. So then what will you do with it? If you're looking for heterogeneous lists, see Shapeless's HList https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless

Comment: There are some ways for converting a list to a tuple at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305290/is-there-way-to-create-tuple-from-listwithout-codegeneration. They could be used to convert an array to a tuple by starting with array.toList.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest I could come up with:

```
scala> "hello_world" split("_") match { case Array(f, s) => (f, s) }
res0: (String, String) = (hello,world)
```

Of course it will throw for other non `Tuple2` cases. You can have this to avoid exceptons:

```
scala> "hello_world" split("_") match { case Array(f, s) => Some(f, s); case _ => None } 
res1: Option[(String, String)] = Some((hello,world))
```

Or with implicits:

```
scala> implicit class ArrayTupple[T](val a: Array[T]) { def pair = a match { case Array(f, s) => (f, s) } }
defined class ArrayTupple

scala> val ss = "hello_world".split("_")
ss: Array[String] = Array(hello, world)

scala> ss.pair
res0: (String, String) = (hello,world)
```

I'm still not very happy with the solution. Seems like you have to either write out all possible cases up to `Tuple22` to make more generic method like `to[Tuple22]` or maybe use macros.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly there's no function, that can convert `Array` of N elements (of course N <= 22) to `TupleN`. There is a proposed change to Scala API[1] to add `:+` and `+:` methods to a tuple, but it has a low priority. What people do in their projects is basically summed up in an SO question [2].

If you do what they propose, and create  classes from `TupleOps2` to Tuple22` it still wouldn't be possible. Look at the code below:

```
def array2Tuple[T](array: Array[T]): TupleN = {
  if(array.length == 2)
    (array(0), array(1))
  else
    array(0) +: array2Tuple(array.drop(1))
}
```

It is still not possible, to deduce N in `TupleN` return type. The problem here is of course with the size of the array vs. size of Tuple. Size of array is contained inside the object, while size of `Tuple` is contained in a type name.

*References:*

- [1] https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7305
- [2] [How to append or prepend an element to a tuple in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349439/how-to-append-or-prepend-an-element-to-a-tuple-in-scala)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do better than

```
"size_known".split("_") match { case Array(a, b) => (a, b) }
```

or

```
Some("size_is_unknown".split("_")) collect { case Array(a, b) => (a, b) }
```

without reinventing some features of [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless), that makes it [easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14727987/645427)