# scala lazy zip of varargs options to option of tuple

Tags: scala, tuples, variadic-functions

i want to combine multiple options to an option of a tuple:

```
val maybeA: Option[Int] = ...
val maybeB: Option[String] = ...

val combined: Option[(Int,String)] = combine(maybeA, maybeB)
```

there are many ways to do this, let's go with:

```
def combined[X,Y](maybeA: Option[X], maybeB: Option[Y]) = maybeA.zip(maybeB).headOption
```

and that's great.

now i wonder, can this be done for varargs and a tuple dynamically somehow?
what would the signature look like?

```
def combine[???](options: Option[?]*): Tuple[?]
```

Comment: this is just theoretically, out of idle curiosity and understanding the limits of the language

Comment: Completely dynamic is impossible. Because what is the input type and what is the output type? However, you may implement it as some kind of **macro** which will infer the correct output type, but that would require that all the values are knew in each use site _(so you can't pass a dynamic list of values)_. However, you will find that the macro is very hard to implement, and that you probably will never need more than x options, so it may be easier to just write each method from 2 options until x options, which will be tedious, but is easily automatable on a code generator script.

Comment: Anyways, if you just need the implementation rather than doing yourself, this is basically what `tupled` will do for any _Applicative_. So, you may just use **cats** and write: `(o1, o2, ..., on).tupled` and it will return an option of tuple of the values.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez the reason i wanted to implement it myself (as an exercise) is because i wanted the options to be evaluated lazily.
the input type is then: => Option[?]*, the options are defined with lazy val and the combiner should not evaluate options unnecessarily once a None is encountered.

i will read up on tupled and Applicative, what i know about tupled is that it's a way to change the input params of a function to a tuple, which isn't exactly what i had in mind, but i'll think about it some more

Comment: Then, I would go with the source generator to generate all the overloads from 2 to n options.

Comment: any computer language experts are welcome to leave a comment elaborating on theoretical concepts/abilities missing from the language that would have made this possible

Comment: If you could append elements to a tuple, it would be trivial. Looks like there is a way to do it. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15349439/302793